# How to change a setting in jquery plugin after it's been initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that is submitting files via ajax to a restful API. In order to do this I am using Hayageeks jQuery Upload File Plugin.

The script is working fine except for when I need one of the settings (the URL), to be changed after initialization. The route will be different for each file depending upon what menu selections are chosen by the user.

**Initialization when document is ready:**

```
$(function(){
    var settings = {
        url: "default_url",
        autoSubmit:false
    }

    uploadObj = $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
});
```

**Event where I want the url to be set:**

```
$("#btnSubmit").on('click', function() {
    uploadObj.uploadFile(
        url: "new_url"
    );

    uploadObj.startUpload();
});
```

What do I need to do in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);` again with the new settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the plugin has an update method that accepts new settings at runtime.

uploadObj.update({url:newUrl,maxFileCount:3,showDownload:false});

I was only able to get this to work in an onchange event though, for some reason it wouldn't work with the click event.